# Stop, Pause and Resume a loop running by a Queue in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, loops, spring-mvc

Suppose I running loop like,
In Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/action/play/{id}")
    public String action(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {

    model.addAttributes("actionList",service.action(id));
    return "redirect:/admin/action";
    }
```

In Service,

```
public String action(int id){
    ArrayList<Contact>a = new ArrayList<>(500);
        Queue<Contact>b = new LinkedList<>();
        // maintain queue size of size 10
        int aIndex  = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            b.add(a.get(aIndex++));
        }
        while (true) {
            if (b.isEmpty()) break; // break when all call are completed
//Here i also want to Pause, Resume and Stop The While loop Here
            Contact frontValue = b.poll(); // get queue's first element and remove it
            if (aIndex  < a.size()) {
                b.add(a.get(aIndex++));
            }
        }
return null;
}
```

And I want to Pause, Resume and Stop this loop. Anyone can suggest me here.

Comment: First,it's a very bad idea to write complex code in controller method,you need to write them in service layer. Second,you can use `thread` to do it

Comment: Actually this code is belongs to Service but for simplicity i only use here in Controller..

Comment: @Sushil you should probably create a bean which does this actions and you should probably use it to toggle the flow. Also, you should be adding a fallback mechanism in case of stopping the execution